# Datadog grok custom java stack parsing and ordered list fields

Tags: java, stack-trace, datadog, grok

I have the following log sample in a grok pipeline in datadog:

```
2022-05-10 11:26:58 [SEVERE]: Log from eu.myapp
  dev added message - eu.myapp.Controller.<init>
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at eu.myapp.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

and the following simple parsing rule

```
log %{_date}%{space}\[%{_status}\]\:%{space}%{data:logger}(\n%{space}%{data:msg}%{space}-%{space}%{data:in})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.msg})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?
```

and the attempt to make it nicer by repeating error.stack so each line is added to array

```
log %{_date}%{space}\[%{_status}\]\:%{space}%{data:logger}(\n%{space}%{data:msg}%{space}-%{space}%{data:in})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.msg})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})?(\n%{space}%{data:error.stack})
```

output simple:

```
{  
  "level": "SEVERE",
  "timestamp": 1652182018000,
  "error": {
    "msg": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "stack": "at eu.myapp.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:48)\n        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\n        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)"
  },
  "in": "eu.myapp.Controller.<init>",
  "msg": "dev added message",
  "logger": "Log from eu.myapp"
 }
```

output nicer:

```
{
  "level": "SEVERE",
  "timestamp": 1652182018000,
  "error": {
    "msg": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "stack": [
      "at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)",
      "at eu.myapp.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:48)",
      "at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)",
      "at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)",
      "at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)"
    ]
  },
  "in": "eu.myapp.Controller.<init>",
  "msg": "dev added message",
  "logger": "Log from eu.myapp"
}
```

As you can see the nicer output is more readable but the list is now unordered. Any way to make the error.stack ordered? Or any other tip or trick to parse this scenario better than im doing now.

I must note I have no control over the log file generation or formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire stack trace should be inside the `error.msg` attribute.

[image: grok parser preview]

So you can update your grok parser to this (You can put back in your status and date helper rules).

```
log %{date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):timestamp}%{space}\[%{word:status}\]\:%{space}%{data:logger}(\n%{space}%{data:msg}%{space}-%{space}%{data:in})?(\n%{data:error.msg})?
```

---

Also I recommend renaming `msg` to `message` and `error.msg` to `error.stack`. You can see they are listed as a [reserved attribute](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/attributes_naming_convention/) in the docs. This will make it so that the stack trace gets its own pretty UI that's a lot cleaner looking.

[image: prettified log in explorer]

Also remember to create the [message](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui#log-message-remapper), [status](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui#log-status-remapper), and [date](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_configuration/processors/?tab=ui#log-date-remapper) remappers in your pipeline so the default values of your log all get updated appropriately.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! And thank you for showing me the ui effect of using reserved attributes and remappers.